# Shouldn't CloudFlare with "Cache Everything" cache everything?

Tags: caching, cloudflare

I have a CloudFlare account and found out that if I use page rules, I could use a more agressive cache setting called "Cache Everything", when reading about this, I understood that it should basically cache everything. I tested it on a site that is completely static, and I set the expiration time to 1 day.

Now after a few days looking at how many requests have been served from the cache and not from the cache, there's no change, still about 25% of the requests have not been served from the cache.

The two rules I've added for Cache Everything are:
http://www.example.com/
and
http://www.example.com/*

Both with Cache Everything and 1 day expiration time.

So my questions are, have I misinterpreted the use of Cache Everything (I thought I only should get one request per page/file each day using this setting), or is something wrong with my rules? Or maybe do I need to wait a few days for the cache to kick in?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you figured it out?

Answer (score 0):

"Or maybe do I need to wait a few days for the cache to kick in?"

Our caching is really designed to function based on the number of requests for the resources (a minimum of three requests), and works basically off of the "hot files" on your site (frequently requested) and is also very much data center related. If we get a lot of requests in one data center, for example, then we would cache the resources.

Also keep in mind that our caching will not cache third-party resources that are on your site (calls to ad platforms, etc.).